# Isomorphism between $GL_3(\mathbb{Z}_2)$ and a subgroup of $S_7$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-isomorphism, general-linear-group

From [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1998843) question, it is clear that the group of $3\times3$ matrices over $\mathbb{Z}_2$ acts transitively as well as faithfully over the set of $3$-tuples. But how can we conclude that the group is isomorphic to a subgroup of $S_7$? Why is not isomorphic to a subgroup of $S_8$? Do we use Cayley theorem here? Thanks beforehand.

Comment: If you read the other question more carefully you will see that it says that the group doesn't act transitively on the set of $3$-tuples, only on the non-zero ones.

Comment: @ancientmathematician yes, got the point

Comment: $S_7$ itself is isomorphic to a subgroup of $S_8$ by fixing one point, so if your group is isomorphic to a subgroup of $S_7$, it surely also is to a subgroup of $S_8$. The interesting question to ask is: "What is the smallest $n$ such that the given group is isomorphic to a subgroup of $S_n$?"

Comment: @Dirk and the answer to that is $7$, right?

Comment: Yes - As the group order ($168$) is divisible by the prime $7$ it can't fit into any smaller symmetric group.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The set $\Bbb Z_2^3$ has $8$ elements, and $GL_3(\Bbb Z_2)$ permutes them. So in that sense, yes, $GL_3(\Bbb Z_2)$ acts like a subgroup of $S_8$.

But there are only seven elements of $\Bbb Z_2^3$ that $GL_3(\Bbb Z_2)$ actually *does* anything to (the action isn't transitive on the entire set of $3$-tuples, as you claim). So it acts as a subgroup of $S_7$ on those elements.